# What are the large free standing imitation circular "flower" arrangements in front of pachinko parlors called?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I see large brightly colored circular imitation flower arrangements that are placed at the entrances of pachinko parlors and want to know what they are called. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditional, round ones [like this](https://pixta.jp/tags/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%B3%20%E8%8A%B1%E8%BC%AA%20%E9%96%8B%E5%BA%97?search_type=2) are called 花輪【はなわ】/花環【はなわ】.

A similar term is スタンド花【ばな】/スタンドフラワー, which is used for similar purposes but tends to refer to real flower arrangement.